# Software licensing system - checking key validity every X seconds

Tags: security, authentication, language-agnostic, licensing

Why don't many softwares check online the license every X seconds?

Suppose I have a license for 5 machines.. I activate all 5 and then reset all *active* machines (so I can activate 5 new ones). The catch? I didn't turn off the previous 5 machines and they still have the activated software running. Every time I activate 5 new machines I always keep previous ones online.

This vicious cycle could be prevented by checking a license validity online every X seconds, but I searched online and couldn't find any reason why no software implements it.

Is there a reason why this system is flawed/unconvenient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the software and how engineers chose to implement licensing. It is not impossible to check every X minutes, but usually there are good reasons not to.

A company might want, for example, to place the machines behind a firewall. Checking the license every few minutes would require an open port, that might be against the security policy of the company. In this occasion, the company is likely to move to a competitor without such requirements.

Many software vendors also perform audits, in order to verify that you are following the contract that you signed when you bought the software (e.g. SAP https://support.sap.com/content/dam/library/SAP%20Support%20Portal/keys-systems-installations/system-management/info-about-system-measurement/documentation/SAP%20System%20Measurement%20Guide.pdf).

Also, not checking that a license was removed from one machine (e.g. by removing the license through the application) before moving it to another machine, should be avoided by a software vendor. However there are occasions that a machine might completely crash. In these occasions, since the customer is always right, you usually provide new licenses, knowing that the customer might be 'cheating'. If machines keep crashing all the time though, and new licenses are required every few days, it will raise suspicions.

Finally, you can find lots of pirated software online. A company might prefer to take the risk of maybe losing some licenses, to losing all. Someone who is likely to pirate software, might as well pirate it for all the machines, if licensing is too strict, and techniques like the one that you described are hard to perform.